# Render Svelte component from a string?

Tags: html, string, svelte

I want to render the following Svelte component :

`<Heading level={1}>This is a title</Heading>`

...but from a string.

I do not want to output a string, I want to output the actual Svelte component but from a string.

I tried this method, which does not work :

```js
<script>
  import Heading from '../components/Heading.svelte';
  const heading = '<Heading level={1}>This is a title</Heading>'
</script>

<main class="rpc-doc-container">
  {@html heading}
</main>
```

Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: You would have to import the component *within* the template and bundle it as well. It is not a simple/trivial problem.

Comment: If you just want to insert a component via code, you can use the [client API](https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api#creating-a-component), though you cannot easily set slots that way.

Comment: Nice. I might as well use props instead of slots then. Not sure it'll work but it's worth giving a try.